# AngularJS ng-options from nested array

Tags: angularjs, multidimensional-array, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

Is it possible to use nested for-loops in an `ng-options` expression?

The following python-style syntax does not work in AngularJS v1.5.8:

```html
ng-options="user for group in userGroups for user in group.userNames"
```

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
       .controller('LoginController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.userGroups = [{
      groupId: 1,
      groupName: 'owner',
      userNames: [
        'John',
        'Mary'
      ]
    },
    {
      groupId: 2,
      groupName: 'admin',
      userNames: [
        'Fred'
      ]
    },
    {
      groupId: 3,
      groupName: 'client',
      userNames: [
        'Company1',
        'Company2',
        'Company3'
      ]
    }
  ];
  $scope.selectedUserName = null;
  $scope.$watch('selectedUserName', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log('selectedUserName changed from', oldValue, 'to', newValue);
  });
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="LoginController">
  <select 
    id="form-login-user" 
    ng-model="selectedUserName" 
    ng-options="user for group in userGroups for user in group.userNames"
  >
    <option></option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please create a jsfiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/Lt7aP/4/ and add your question example. Thanks

Comment: @maverickosama92 added snippet

Comment: anddero: you are trying to display usernames array?

Comment: @maverickosama92 In this example, yes.

Comment: is this you're looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/jpn6mqtx/? Please see this.

Comment: @maverickosama92 Not quite. This may solve a specific case, where you want to iterate a property of each element. I am looking for a generic solution, without `optgroup`s, where the resulting drop-down list is non-hierarchical. Simple example: iterating a multi-dimensional array like `[['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5']]` which should display drop-down options 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5.

Comment: ngOptions doesn't support multi-dimensional arrays as far as I know. You have to flatten your array. Or you can change your html select to optgroup if you want to deal with muli-dimensional arrays.